# Parsing text file for calculations

Tags: java, parsing

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do which should direct me to the right track

I have a txt file like:

```
  2*3
  4-4
  4+2  
  8*1
```

For each line I need to separate numbers and identify the type of action (e.g. multiplication in the 1st line) so I could create the following output:

```
  6
  0
  6
  8
```

- Should I use a delimiter to separate them (not quite sure how to do
  that, since the delimiter might be +,-,* and /)?
- Or use a for loop? (I'd like to avoid this one for sure...)

Comment: Can you have more complex equations like `2*3+3` or will you always have just a single operation?

Comment: always single operations only

Comment: Is it possible to have (2*3)/(4-4) or is it only **one** operation?

Comment: you could use a regex but why not use a math expression parser?

Comment: won't be more complex as it is already

Comment: Do you have control over the text file? In other words, could you format the output to be 6(*)3? That way, it would be easy to separate each part.

Comment: Can you have more than one digit or negative numbers?

Comment: I used double in my example because of the division operator. I assume you need the floating point result, don't you? For example for 5/2 you want 2 or 2.5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution (with no error checking, you add it if you need it) that would work is:

**myfile.txt**

```
2 + 2
```

**code snippet**

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("myfile.txt"));
double firstNumber = sc.nextDouble();
String operation = sc.next("[+-/\\*]");
double secondNumber = sc.nextDouble();

double result;
if("+".equals(operation))
  result = firstNumber + secondNumber;
else if("-".equals(operation))
  result = firstNumber - secondNumber;
else if("*".equals(operation))
  result = firstNumber * secondNumber;
else if("/".equals(operation))
  result = firstNumber / secondNumber;
else
  System.out.println("Operation unrecognized");

System.out.println(firstNumber + operation + secondNumber + " = " + result);
```

Comment: I tried this one at the first time. It throws java.util.InputMismatchException trying to get firstNumber

Comment: You need to add spacing for the operator in `myfile.txt`: `2 + 2` (note the spaces surrounding the `+` sign).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a very simplistic answer, not very robust if the data ins not formed as you described.

```
static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([0-9]+)([+-/\\*])([0-9]+)");
public static int calculate(String arg) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(arg);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        int a = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
        int b = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(3));
        String operator = matcher.group(2);
        if ("+".equals(operator)) {
            return a+b;
        } else if ("-".equals(operator)) {
            return a-b;
        } else if ("/".equals(operator)) {
            return a/b;
        } else if ("*".equals(operator)) {
            return a*b;
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not parse '" + arg + " '");
}
```

It parses the string as three groups, first group of numbers, then one of (+, -, / or *) and then another group of numbers.

Answer (score 1):

```
//puesdocode
while end of file not reached
{
   int x = next int from input file
   char ch = next char from input file
   int y = next int from input file
   int z;
   switch(ch)
   {
      case '*': z = x*y; break;
      case '/': z = x/y; break;
      case '-': z = x-y; break;
      case '+': z = x+y; break;
   }
   println to file (z);
}
```

Comment: next int from input file - what's this? I mean I know it's not a code, but still not sure how to get that x. And wht's more: as far i know non-numeric cases are avalible from java 7. I'm forced to use Java 6

Answer (score 0):

Instead of building your own (as this can become complex as you start supporting multiple operations/operands per line), I suggest using [arity - Arithmetic Engine for Java](http://code.google.com/p/arity/). Below is sample example from their site.

```
import org.javia.arity.Symbols;
import org.javia.arity.SyntaxException;

public class Try {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws SyntaxException {
        Symbols symbols = new Symbols();
        double value = symbols.eval("2^10");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The ECMAScript (JavaScript) engine of the [ScriptEngine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html) can do the calculations line by line.